# Screen size in API level 10 and forward?

Tags: android

I want to get the screen size and I'm using a device that has API level 10. I'm using `Display` to get the width and height, but I'm getting a message in Eclipse that this is deprecated. A better and newer way is to use `DisplayMetrics` for apps that have a newer API, but there is no support for `DisplayMetrics` in API 10. How should I be doing to handle this issue?

Old(deprecated)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
screenWidth = display.getWidth();
screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

New

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.heightPixels;
metrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: why don't you check the android build first and then call the required method based on your build version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check the API level like this:

```
int screenWidth = 0;
int screenHeight = 0;   
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 10) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    screenHeight = display.getHeight();
} else {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
}
```

But [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) was added in `API level 1`. So actually you only need the else-clause.

Comment: Nice. It works without API Level - related problems. But what about converting them to dp's ?

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` directly on my activity object. It exactly gives me the screen size. It works fine as it is available from API level 1.